# How to install lets encrypt ssl in amazon linux AMI?

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt

How to install lets encrypt SSL in amazon Linux AMI.i want to implement the lets encrypt SSL for my domain.

Comment: let's encrypt in Amazon Linux 2. ref: https://superuser.com/a/1124409/1259203

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of solutions online; I think you have to keep on trying until you find one that works for you. After *a lot* of experimentation, what worked for me was following the certbot instructions for Apache and CentOS 6. The official link is [here](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/centos6-apache), but for consistency:

Run the following commands in the terminal:

1. Download Certbot

```
wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto
sudo mv certbot-auto /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto
sudo chown root /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto
sudo chmod 0755 /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto
```

2. Execute Certbot

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto --apache
```

If there's an error message, read the warning and run (if you feel comfortable):

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto --apache --debug
```

Here, you may be asked to complete some fairly intuitive questions to configure your installation. If not, what worked for me won't work for you. :(

3. Automate Renewal

Test to see if renewing your certificate works:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto renew --dry-run
```

If so, navigate to your system's crontab (usually somewhere around `/etc/crontab/`) and add the following code to check (and run, if necessary) and auto-renewal at midnight and noon everyday:

```
0 0,12 * * * python -c 'import random; import time; time.sleep(random.random() * 3600)' && /usr/local/bin/certbot-auto renew
```

Comment: https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto is no longer supported: [Certbot-Auto](https://certbot.eff.org/docs/install.html#certbot-auto).

Answer (score 1):

Here I will explain how to configure let's encrypt in Linux AMI. I did it successfully in my Linux AMI.i followed the following steps to get it done.

```
 1. SSH into your server.
 2. Download certbot (the Let’s Encrypt client need to install for renew and install ssl): **wget https://dl.eff.org/certbot-auto** then **chmod a+x certbot-auto**
 3. Run certbot to fetch your certificates.follow the below code
    sudo ./certbot-auto --debug -v --server https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory certonly -d YOUR_DOMAIN [Replace your Domain in YOUR_DOMAIN placeholde]

 4. while generating it will ask you the recover or support email please add your email.

 5.  certbot will place your certs in the following paths…

      Certificate: /etc/letsencrypt/live/YOUR_DOMAIN/cert.pem
      Full Chain: /etc/letsencrypt/live/YOUR_DOMAIN/fullchain.pem
      Private Key: /etc/letsencrypt/live/YOUR_DOMAIN/privkey.pem

 6. Go to your apache config where you created a virtual host it can be either in httpd.conf or conf.d.

 7. Add the virtual host for 443 port

    <VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin ADMIN_EMAIL
    ServerName YOUR_DOMAIN
    ServerAlias www.YOUR_DOMAIN
    DocumentRoot "YOUR FOLDER PATH"
      AllowEncodedSlashes On

    ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd/YOUR_DOMAIN_error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/httpd/YOUR_DOMAIN-sslaccess.log" common

<Directory YOUR FOLDER PATH>
                DirectoryIndex index.php
                Options -Indexes
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile      /etc/letsencrypt/live/YOUR_DOMAIN/cert.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/letsencrypt/live/YOUR_DOMAIN/privkey.pem
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/YOUR_DOMAIN/fullchain.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Certbot if you are running CentOS 7 or 8 since Certbot-auto is deprecated and doesn't work beyond CentOS 6.

You can check which CentOS you are running by using the following command.

```
rpm -E %{rhel}
```

And use this [tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html#install) from amazon to install Certbot in Amazon Linux

```
sudo yum update
sudo yum install -y certbot python2-certbot-apache
```

If you get "Package not found" error, then try the [Prepare to Install](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/SSL-on-amazon-linux-2.html#prepare) section from the same blog.

```
sudo wget -r --no-parent -A 'epel-release-*.rpm' https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/
sudo rpm -Uvh dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/x86_64/Packages/e/epel-release-*.rpm
sudo yum-config-manager --enable epel*
```